# AceFEM: Manipulating Elements Domain

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I'm trying to change the Domain of an Element.
For that purpose usage of 
[image]
makes sense for me.
Anyway, it applies I've done a syntax error here.
Can anyone tell how to do it right ?

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain[{
    {"B1", "ML:SEPEQ1DFLEQ1DHooke", {}},
    {"B2", "ML:SEPEQ1DFLEQ1DHooke", {}}
   }];
SMTAddMesh[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], "B1", "Q1", {3, 3}];
SMTAnalysis[];

(*Current Domain of Elmt.5*)
SMTElementData[{5},"Domain"](*evaluates {"B1"}*)

(*Try to set Elmt.5 to Domain "B2"*)
SMTElementData[{5},"Domain",{"B2"}]
```

Comment: I have edited your question to add `SMTAnalysis`. Without this your example doesn't demonstrate the error you are asking about. I hope you don't mind...

Answer (score 4):

I agree that according to documentation your code should work. I don't know why it doesn't, but this is a workaround.

```
SMTElementData["Domain"]
(* {"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1"} *)

SMTElementData[{5}, "SpecIndex", SMTDomainData["B2", "SpecIndex"]];

SMTElementData["Domain"]
(* {"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1"} *)
```